# VirtualBox shared folders from OS X host are not writable on Ubuntu guest

Tags: permissions, osx, virtualbox, shared-folders

I'm running an Ubuntu guest VirtualBox instance.  I have a host folder `web-server` being shared with the guest.  On the guest, there are two users which need writable access to the shared folder: the daemon user `www-data`, and a regular SSH login user which I'll call `jdoe`, who are both members of the group I'll call `www-users`

On the host, the folder looks like:

```
$ ls -al /Users/jdoe/web-server
drwxrwsr-x  14 jdoe  staff   448 Jun 19 11:04 .
```

On the guest, the folder is mounted with:

```
$ mount -t vboxsf -ogid=www-users web-server /usr/share/host/web-server
```

And running `mount` shows:

```
web-server on /usr/share/host/web-server type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
```

I've also attempted to add `jdoe` to the `vboxsf` group; `jdoe` has the following groups:

```
jdoe adm sudo vboxsf ssl-cert www-users
```

While the setup appears to work on Windows and Ubuntu hosts, on OS X the guest user does not have writable access to the folder.  The permissions on the guest appear as:

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/host/web-server
drwxrwxr-x 1 root www-users  448 Jun 19 11:04 .
```

But when logged in as `jdoe`, I cannot write to the folder:

```
$ touch /usr/share/host/web-server/foo
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/host/web-server/foo': Permission denied
```

If I change the mount to `-ouid=jdoe,gid=www-users`, then `jdoe` can write to it, and if I change it to `-ouid=www-data,gid=www-users`, then `www-data` can write to it.  In either case, other members of the `www-users` cannot write to the folder.

Another note, I cannot rely on VirtualBox auto-mount, because this needs to work as it does in production, where drives get mounted on the fly.

Comment: Did you try using `rw` option of `mount`? `man mount`.

Comment: On the guest, what groups is jdoe a member of?

Comment: I verified the mount is mounted with `rw` by default and I've edited the question with the groups: `jdoe adm sudo vboxsf ssl-cert www-users`

Comment: (As an alternative to whatever other answers are given) I had similar problems in the past and now I use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/) to set up VMs on OS X and everything is much easier as it takes care of mounting etc and I use shell scripts to sort out the details like users and dir access. Just in case you can't get any further with your problem and start looking for ways around.

Comment: Please can you specify the version(s) of Ubuntu you are testing, to date this question? Since this seems so weird, I would suggest mentioning the version number of VirtualBox as well.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this ?

```
mount -t vboxsf -ouid=root,gid=www-users,fmode=664,dmode=775 web-server /usr/share/host/web-server
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me, for when nginx's root is a mount point from virtualbox

Comment: Thank you, indeed the part `fmode=664,dmode=775` fixed a similar issue for me when I was unable to pull git updates on a shared folder.